# Is there a function to give the output [1, 2, 3, 12, 23,...]?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I'm trying to write a program, that handles arrays of numbers. These arrays should be a combination of these numbers, but they have to be in order.

If I have three numbers [1, 2, 3] the arrays should be 
[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3].

At the moment it is working with some hardcoded for-Loops, but I can't figure out, how to do it with a function.

```
int numElements = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < numElements - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < numElements; j++)
  {
    arr.add (new int[]{i, j});
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numElements - 2; i++)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < numElements - 1; j++)
  {
    for (int k = j + 1; k < numElements; k++)
    {
      arr.add (new int[]{i, j, k});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tag the language. What you are seeking for is called **permutation**.

Comment: The language is not that important for me.

It might be just a part of permutation. The output [2,1,3] would be invalid, cause they have to be in order

Comment: @MarkusZeller Permutation uses all elements and only alters the order. This is combination.

Comment: You can do it with a function if you put your code inside a function and return the combinations from it. Please explain what problems you're having in more detail.

Comment: Are you looking for some built-in function, or how to convert your existing code in a function?

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for this point, I'll try to work with it!

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy i don't think there will be some build-in function for this, so I'm trying to convert my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate all subsets except for empty one. There are `2^n-1` such subsets and we can match every subset to integer value in range.
Pseudocode

```
for (int i = 1; i < (1<<n); i++){
   x = i;
   k = 0; 
   subset = [];
   while (x) {
       if (x & 1)           //if k-th bit is set in x
           subset.add(A[k]);
       x >>= 1;         //shift right
       k++;
   }
   print subset;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in python you could use combinations to at least keep the correct order, but you would have to iterate over all lengths:

```py
from itertools import combinations 
# all combinations of length 2
comb = combinations([1, 2, 3], 2) 

# Print the combinations 
for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
```

Output:
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)

Comment: OP wants all subsets of the array.